# using classes to create checkboxes in tktinter python

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, widget, tk-toolkit

im trying to use classes to create multiple checkboxes in tktinter python, but for some reason the checkboxes aren't showing, this is the error i'm getting 
`AttributeError: 'crop' object has no attribute 'tk'`
And heres my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk  # python 3
screen = Tk()

class crop:

    def __init__(self,sizename,sizevar,onvar):
        sizevar= StringVar
        self.tk.Checkbutton(screen, text=sizename, variable=sizevar, onvalue=onvar, offvalue='no')
        self.pack()


def main():
    first = crop('2.5','twofive','twofiveon')
    second = crop('3','three','threeon')
screen.mainloop()    
main()
```

thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.

First, you need to call `mainloop` after you call `main`, not before.

Second, `sizevar= StringVar` needs to be `sizevar= StringVar()`.

Third -- and this is the line that is throwing the error -- you are trying to call `self.tk.Checkbutton` but your `crop` object hasn't defined an attribute named `tk`. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but my guess is that you are just trying to call the tk checkbutton which means the code should be `tk.Checkbutton(...)`

The next problem is with `self.pack()` - `self` is the `crop` object. It is not a widget so it doesn't have a `pack` method. It appears that your intention is to pack the checkbutton, so you need to save a reference to the checkbutton and then call `pack` on it (eg: `self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(...); self.cb.pack()`)

Another problem is that you're importing tkinter twice. You should only do it once. You need to remove both `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter.ttk import *`. Then, use `tk.` or `ttk.` as a prefix when referring to tkinter and ttk objects.

A final issue is that you're not following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines, making your code harder for other programmers to understand. Specifically, `crop` needs to be `Crop`.

Putting that all together, your code should<sup>1</sup> look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

screen = tk.Tk()

class Crop:

    def __init__(self,sizename,sizevar,onvar):
        sizevar= tk.StringVar()
        self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(screen, text=sizename, variable=sizevar, onvalue=onvar, offvalue='no')
        self.cb.pack()


def main():
    first = Crop('2.5','twofive','twofiveon')
    second = Crop('3','three','threeon')

main()
screen.mainloop()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I say *should* because it's not 100% clear what you want to do. Because of the way you originally did the imports it's unclear if you're intending to use the ttk version of the `Checkbutton` widget or the tk version. This is one of the reasons why wildcard imports are bad when importing tkinter. If you want to use the ttk checkbutton, you need to change that one line to this:

```
self.cb = ttk.Checkbutton
```

Comment: Wow Thankyou so much, that was a really good explanation, to be honest I don’t know the difference between tk and Ttk I was just following a tutorial I was watching, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like:

```
  def __init__(self,sizename,sizevar,onvar):
        global screen # or pass it as __init__ parameter
        sizevar= StringVar
        b= tk.Checkbutton(screen, text=sizename, variable=sizevar, onvalue=onvar, offvalue='no')
        b.pack()
```

Comment: that just takes away the use of classes, i need to use classes to shorten my code as i will be making like 20 checkboxes, thanks for your help though

Comment: No it does not. You need to identify what you want to retrieve from each crop instance and make it a property of the class eg `self.sizevar = StringVar`

Comment: im very confused could you show me in full code please? thanks

Comment: There's no need to declare `screen` as global since they aren't trying to modify the variable. A global variable is readable inside functions without declaring them global. Declaring it might be a good practice, but that doesn't answer the OP's question.